# Problem using ESI ESP1010

Tags: drivers, audio

I just bought and installed an ESP1010 sound card and everything went well as expected. However, once I tried to record vocals to test the microphone it will only record in either the Left Channel in Input 1 (XLR Input) or the Right Channel in Input 2 (XLR Input). I have installed the PCI card with the latest drivers but nothing changes.

I need to record in stereo, so how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also install [the software for the ESP1010 sound card](http://www.windriverupdate.com/About-sound/ESI/ESI-ESP1010-PCI-audio-interface-driver-1.14-Win2000/XP-1434.html)? If you have, the setting of the control panel is default so you might need to change the setting as to meet your need. You can change the input signal level on all channels by clicking and dragging the fader bar. The number on the bottom shows the relative amount in dB. Clicking this number enables you to mute the channel. So you might have muted one channel and you should enable that channel again. To use a microphone, you also need to change the input level to “M” from “L”. One more thing you need to pay attention to is that if your microphone requires 48V phantom power, you can enable that on the hardware when an optional external power supply is connected to the ESP 1010 rack. It is not recommended to enable both +12V and +48V phantom power simultaneously.